# Custom action for context menu in Site Content and Structure

Tags: custom-actions, content-and-structure

I'm trying to add a custom action to the context menu in the Site Content and Structures view:

[image]

However I can't find the location ID I need to use - `Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu` doesn't seem to do the trick.

There is a great [list by John Holiday](http://johnholliday.net/resources/customactions.html) and the [list on MSDN,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx) but neither does help me.
I'm close to just using Javascript to attach to the menu. Anyone know how to access the item level / list level menus?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is the `EditControlBlock` to which you are trying to add the custom action.